# LinQ converting results to list of class

Tags: vb.net, linq

Using VS 2013(VB) and SQL server 2012.

I have a class that retrieves 5 variables from the DB.  I use a module called DayAheadSettingsDAL to connect to the DB.  I have just started to try LinQ but I having issues.

The code is

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Module DayAheadSettingsDAL

    Public Function getDASettings() As List(Of DayAheadSettings)

        Dim result As List(Of DayAheadSettings)
        Dim db As New GMConnectionDataContext

        result = db.DayAhead_Settings
        Return result

    End Function

End Module
```

I get the following error when I run the page.

> Unable to cast object of type 'SingleResult`1[DayAhead_SettingsResult]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DayAheadSettings]'.

db.dayahead_Settings is a stored procedure that returns a set of results with differing types.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: What is the return type of `db.DayAhead_Settings`?

Comment: it shows the type in the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Linq2Sql` returns data from *Stored Procedures* as a `SingleResult` with all the fields from the result set.

So one option is not to declare the type of your result set:

```
Dim result = db.DayAhead_Settings
```

And convert this result to the correct type of `List(Of DayAHeadSettings)`